# Convert Character to Integer

Tags: abap

I have this ABAP code:

```
CLEAR NEGATIIVNE.
DATA gv_negativenumericvalue_txt TYPE CHAR40.
SELECT SINGLE NETWR INTO NEGATIIVNE
  FROM VBRK
  WHERE VBELN = VBRK-VBELN.
IF DEBIT_CREDIT = 'CRED'.
  NEGATIIVNE = NEGATIIVNE * -1.
ELSE.
  NEGATIIVNE = NEGATIIVNE.
  ENDIF.
WRITE NEGATIIVNE TO gv_negativenumericvalue_txt.
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '.' in gv_negativenumericvalue_txt with ''.
CALL FUNCTION 'CLOI_PUT_SIGN_IN_FRONT'
 CHANGING
  value = gv_negativenumericvalue_txt.
CALL FUNCTION 'MOVE_CHAR_TO_NUM '
  EXPORTING
    CHR = gv_negativenumericvalue_txt
  IMPORTING
    NUM = NEGATIIVNE
  EXCEPTIONS
    CONVT_NO_NUMBER = 1
    CONVT_OVERFLOW  = 2
    OTHERS          = 3.
write:/ gv_negativenumericvalue_txt.
```

What I need to do is write variable `gv_negativenumericvalue_txt into variable NEGATIIVNE` but I can't do it any way :/ I need it do show the value NEGATIIVNE in my ALV layout.

Right now the code works fine but as soon as I try to do something like this -

`NEGATIIVNE = gv_negativenumericvalue_txt` I get dump saying that system can't recognize the character as number.

Comment: What Do You expect ? This is base programming skills. You need to cast properly, or try to use move gv_negativenumericvalue_txt to NEGATIIVNE.

Comment: Are you sure that the number contained in `gv_negativenumericvalue_txt` has a valid number representation? Also I do not understand why you need to convert when you already have the value of it available in the code context.

Comment: @Jagger, I think the sign in front ruins it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the requirement you got is that the net value of billing documents should be shown in 1 format, not respecting the settings of the user which control the decimal notation.

The only way to do that, is to use a 21 char (you dont need 40) field instead of NEGATIIVNE in your ALV.

On a side note, because `NEGATIIVNE = NEGATIIVNE.` does not do anything I would write

```
IF DEBIT_CREDIT = 'CRED'.
  NEGATIIVNE = NEGATIIVNE * -1.
ELSE.
  NEGATIIVNE = NEGATIIVNE.
ENDIF.
```

as

```
IF DEBIT_CREDIT = 'CRED'.
  NEGATIIVNE = NEGATIIVNE * -1.
ENDIF.
```